# Changing the background color for Form2

Tags: vb.net, background

i have two `RadioButtons` one for `Light Blue` and the other for `Ghost White` and a `button` to show the next Form (`Form2`)
i want to be able to check on a `Radio Button` and the `backcolor of form2` changes to the checked `Radio Button`
this is what i have on my coding so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SecondForm.Show()
    End Sub

Private Sub rbLightBlue_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbLightBlue.CheckedChanged
    If rbLightBlue.Checked Then
        SecondForm.BackColor = (Color.LightBlue)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rbGhostWhite_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbGhostWhite.CheckedChanged
    If rbGhostWhite.Checked Then
        SecondForm.BackColor = (Color.GhostWhite)
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem am having is making the background color change on Form2.
Any answer for this question will be very helpful.

Comment: Your code should work, what exactly is happening? any error's ?

Comment: Well am not getting any error when i run it. The thing is when i run it nothing happens in my second Form i thought maybe it was because i had to put some coding on my second form to get the command sent to it by Form1.

Comment: the radio buttons,button in first form or second form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are doing, it probably has to do with how you are creating your SecondForm, this code does work, see if it helps you narrow it down.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim SecondForm As Form2 = New Form2
    Private Sub rbLightBlue_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbLightBlue.CheckedChanged
        If DirectCast(sender, RadioButton).Checked Then
            SecondForm.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rbGhostWhite_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbGhostWhite.CheckedChanged
        If DirectCast(sender, RadioButton).Checked Then
            SecondForm.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SecondForm.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```